# Chart.js bar chart is overflowing its containing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

[Chart.js](http://chartjs.org)

I can't get this stupid chart to stay in its container when `padding` has been applied to the container. It doesn't matter if the `responsive` option is set to `true`.

[image]

It also doesn't matter what I set `box-sizing` to. What's the purpose of the `responsive` option if not to fit it's container?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. I don't think Chart.js calculates the dimensions of the canvas correctly. As stated in the answer another container without any padding will solve the problem.

Answer (score 15):

As with most CSS, the answer is to use another wrapper!

I had the same problem (and I'm using box sizing)

Just put one div around your canvas! (the divs will inherit the box sizing)

```
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Good luck

:)

Answer (score 9):

This will solve the issue

Javascript:

```
new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    responsive:true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
});
```

ES6

```
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;
```